# why my daterangepicker demo can not run on localhost?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I have a task that should use daterangepicker,so I visted to http://www.daterangepicker.com/ and learn about it ,I just try the simplest demo in my codepen,it is very easy.

But when I try to export the code zip to my computer ,and unzip the package and run the demo on my chrome and firefox ,the result is that they  can not show the dropdown meau and can not get a date pick,I want to know why and how to deal with it.

the html code like this:

```
<!-- Include Required Prerequisites -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.css" />

<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />



<p>this is a daterangepicker demo</p>
<input type="text" value="01/01/2016-12/30/2016" name="daterange"></input>
```

the JS code like this :

```
$(function() {
  $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker();
});
```

this is my codepen :http://codepen.io/zhangolve/pen/WxrNAL?editors=1111

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console? Also make sure you are not including 2 different versions of _jQuery_ on the same page. Also, make sure that jQuery is using the `$` variable, and its not another javascript framework.

Comment: the chrome console show the error:
daterangepicker.js:1595 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).daterangepicker is not a function index.js

But this is the wander why I can run the code in codepen successfully.

Comment: @palaѕн anyway ,thank you ,the problem have been solved

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your js loading sequence :

Loading sequence should be :

```
 1. jquery.js    
 2. moment.js
 3. daterangepicker.js
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Bugfixer/L04oob66/

Comment: thank you ,it helped me .actually,when I write code at codepen,I also noticed the issue about Loading sequence ,just forget to check it in the export index.html .